# Border wont be full width when overflowing x

Tags: html, css

```css
.list {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex >  h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<div class="flex">
<h2>Title</h2>
<h2>Title</h2>
<h2>Title</h2>
<h2>Title</h2>

<h2>Title</h2>

</div>
<div class="items">

</div>
</div>
```

In my app, whenever I have an overflow, the border isn't stretching to full container width, how can I fix this? I've added sample code.

[image]

Comment: Hi. In your sample code, the border is working as expected. Please post a version of your problem.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy , no it doesn't, when you minimize the screen window to very small

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bY4uDzJ.png , the border should be stretched to the end